# High CPU Usage when updating @State or @Published value repeatedly - frequently in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, scroll, state, lag

I wanted to animate the a header view based on the scroll on the list but the header was in a zstack overlaying my list.
Therefore i used a
`@State var offset: CGFloat`
to store my scroll offset and update my header view accordingly, but doing so caused a 80% cpu usage and a terrible lag while scrolling

I tried everything imaginable but was unable to resolve this issue, from using EnviornmentObjects to throttling updates using Combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general updating Observables and listening to changes in swiftui costs a lot and should not be used on frequently updated values like scroll offset.
I was able to get the animation I wanted by putting the header as the first item in the list and offsetting it equal to negative of the scroll offset.
this way scroll offset is not saved in an `@State` therefore the cpu usage problem is solved

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    let minY = geometry.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY
    VStack {
         HeaderView(
                offset: minY
            )
            .zIndex(10)
            .offset(y: -minY)

         //rest of the scroll view
    }
}
```

your scrollView does't need to be in the same file or geometry reader, only the same `CoordinatorSpace` must be applied to it

```
ScrollView {
    //scroll content which also includes the HeaderView
}
.coordinateSpace(name: "SCROLL")
```